# Thymeleaf not displaying correct string on page but prints correctly from model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a webpage that shows the text in a different language based on the user's location. For this I am using property files with the strings that are to be displayed in each language, and loading them as a resource bundle, and then adding those strings to the model so that I can access them in Thymeleaf. Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model, Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang/index", locale);
        addResourceBundleToModel(model, rb);
        System.out.println(model.getAttribute("test2"));
        return "index";
    }

    private void addResourceBundleToModel(Model model,
                                          ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        for (String key : resourceBundle.keySet()) {
            model.addAttribute(key, resourceBundle.getString(key));
        }
    }
}
```

And the thymeleaf file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <a th:text ="#{test2}"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page and `model.getAttribute("test2")` prints to the console, I get the string I want, namely "abc" as a test string. But "abc" does not show in the browser, instead I get `??test2_en_US??`. What is the problem with my code? How do I get it to show "abc" on the browser? Also, I tried using `@RestController` annotation and returning `model.getAttribute("test2").toString()` and this way I got "abc" to show up on the browser, but I can't get it to work with Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a bean for your resource (say messages.properties in your resources folder) somewhere in your config class like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10);
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

In your messages.properties file put key value similar to this:

```
welcome.text=Welcome to Thymeleaf Layouts with SpringBoot
```

Somewhere in your view simply put similar to this:

```
<h1 th:text="#{welcome.text}"></h1>
```

Haven't tried your code. But you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootThymeleafTemplate) for working sample. I just added message.properties and the th:text tag in my html.

Comment: Didn´t work for some reason... Even removing the Locale from the parameters I still get the same string. Or removing that code all together and using just the default, without setting routes still prints the same string

Comment: After following the steps I mentioned, try removing everything from your controller index method’s body except -  return “index”; Then share the outcome.

Comment: I think the issue lies somewhere else, because even with no code at all, just the Controller with a Model, it still has the same output. I tried deleting all the files completely so there is no trace of properties or anything, just the controller and the html,  and manually added an attribute to the model using `model.addAttribute("test", "test string");` and still got `??test_en_US??`on the browser

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was in my index.html file. Instead of using `<a th:text ="#{test2}"></a>` with a #, I changed it to `<a th:text ="${test2}"></a>` with a dollar sign. That fixed the issue and it is now rendering the correct strings.